# How to configure Working Time in odoo?

Tags: time, odoo, odoo-10, timesheet.js

I have been using the Timesheets module in odoo 10. For the Working Time it takes from monday to friday. But I want to add one saturday for every month. That is, each month should calculate 1st saturday along with the other working days. How can I achieve this without using the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can define working hours from **Employee's Contracts** Form. In it, there is one field which is **Working Schedule** and set Working hours from there.

Hope it will helps you.

Thanks,

Comment: Your answer does not address the main part of the question. Is it possible to only add Working Hours for the first Saturday of each month?